# load image asynchronously in uiimageview in Xamarin Monotouch

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have table cell, in that I am showing multiple images in scrollview horizontally, I need load images into imageview asynchronously, that means I need to place default placefolder.png file, if the images are not loaded.

If the images are loaded I need to replace placeholder.png with the loaded images.

Can anyone please help me..

```
_image = new UIImageView(FromUrl(contentItem.FilePath, cachedImages)) { Tag = 1001 };
_imagePath = contentItem.FilePath;
_image.Frame = new RectangleF(x, 0, 250, _image.Image.CGImage.Height);
x = x + (Convert.ToInt32( Bounds.Width));
        scrollwidth = scrollwidth + Convert.ToInt32( Bounds.Width);
_scrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF (scrollwidth, _image.Image.CGImage.Height);
_scrollView.Add (_image);
```

Comment: where are you loading the images from? That would determine what sort of asynchronous methods you can call to retrieve them

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a table cell and you can't be certain if the cell is still the same when the task finishes I would create a download task similar to this first:

```
    public async static Task<string> DownloadImage(string fileWebAddress, string localPath)
    {
        await new WebClient ().DownloadFileTaskAsync (url, fileName);
        return localPath;
    }
```

Then when creating the cell you would first check if you have already downloaded the image to local storage:

```
if (File.Exist(contentItem.FilePath))
{
    SetImage(_image, contentItem.FilePath);
}
```

If not, then start async download and when it returns you check if the task was for the current cell (contentItem cannot be local function variable, it needs to be cell variable that can change):

```
else
{
        DownloadImage(contentItem.WebPath, contentItem.FilePath).ContinueWith (t =>
            {
                if (contentItem.FilePath == t.Result)
                {
                    SetImage(_image, t.Result);
                }
            });
}
```